# Getting strange value

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I'm currently learning about functions in C++ and am currently working on a homework assignment with functions being the main thing.

Currently, I'm trying to make a grade calculator with every operation of the process being split into a function of its own.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void getHWGrades(int homeworks[], int size)
{
    cout << "\nEnter the grades, out of 100 points, for the 9 homeworks you completed." << endl;
    cout << "Note that Homework 10 is given to you for free, but is the same grade \nas homework 9.\n" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        cout << "Homework " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> homeworks[i];

        while (homeworks[i] > 100 || homeworks[i] < 0)
        {
            cout << "Invalid grade, input homework grade again: ";
            cin >> homeworks[i];
        }
    }
    homeworks[9] = homeworks[8];
    cout << "Homework 10: " << homeworks[9];
}

double quizAverage()
{
    double quizPts;

    cout << "Input your in class quiz average: ";
    cin >> quizPts;
    return quizPts;
}

double labAverage()
{
    double labPts;

    cout << "Input your lab average: ";
    cin >> labPts;
    return labPts;
}

double teamProject()
{
    double teamPts;

    cout << "Input your team project grade: ";
    cin >> teamPts;
    return teamPts;
}

int exam1()
{
    int exam1Pts;

    cout << "Input your exam1 grade: ";
    cin >> exam1Pts;
    return exam1Pts;
}

int exam2()
{
    int exam2Pts;

    cout << "Input your exam2 grade: ";
    cin >> exam2Pts;
    return exam2Pts;
}

double hwAverage(int homeworks[], int size)
{
    double total = 0;
    double homeworkAverage = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        total = total + homeworks[i];
    }

    homeworkAverage = (total*1.0) / 10;
    return homeworkAverage;
}


double currentPoints(double& quizPts, double& labPts, double& teamPts, double& homeworkAverage, int& exam1Pts, int& exam2Pts)
{
    double totalPts = ((quizPts / 100.0) * 10) + ((labPts / 100.0) * 10) + ((teamPts / 100.0) * 15) + ((homeworkAverage / 100.0) * 20) + ((exam1Pts / 100.0) * 10) + ((exam2Pts / 100.0) * 15);
    cout << "\nYour current points (out of the 80 total available), stand at: " << totalPts;
    return totalPts;
}

double currentAverage(double& totalPts)
{
    double availableAverage = totalPts*(100.0 / 80);
    cout << "\nYour current average is: " << availableAverage;

    return availableAverage;
}

int main()
{    
    // keep the console from closing in visual studio
    char charer;

    double totalPts;

    double quizPts, labPts, teamPts, homeworkAverage;
    int exam1Pts, exam2Pts;

    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
    int hwArray[ARRAY_SIZE];
    getHWGrades(hwArray, ARRAY_SIZE);

    quizAverage();
    labAverage();
    teamProject();
    exam1();
    exam2();

    currentPoints(quizPts, labPts, teamPts, homeworkAverage, exam1Pts, exam2Pts);
    currentAverage(totalPts);

    cin >> charer;
}
```

My issue, which I believe lies in the functions `currentPoints` and `currentAverage`, is that when I run this `totalPts` outputs as `-5.09078e+61` and as a follow up result with the `currentAverage` function, `availableAverage` outputs as `-1.157e+62`.

I'm sure that the issue has to do with how I'm passing the values from function to function (which I doubt I'm doing correctly).

How would I go about fixing this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `double quizPts, labPts, teamPts, homeworkAverage;`  These are all uninitialized when you call your `currentPoints` function.

Comment: The first thing you should do, both to understand the problem yourself and to make it accessible for others to help you, is to reduce it to the relevant core. I doubt that all 127 lines contribute to the problem. For example, you can safely remove functions like `quizAverage()` which don't change the global state and where you ignore the return value.

Comment: You rae passing uninitialised value to function currentPoints.You have to assign it like quizPts=quizAverage(); labPts=labAverage();....so on and totalPts= currentPoints(quizPts, labPts, teamPts, homeworkAverage, exam1Pts, exam2Pts);

Comment: Heinrich - Yeah, I also doubt it, it's just that the function I'm having problems with calls upon values from the other functions so I thought it best that I include the related info.

user1438832 - Thanks for pointing out how to fix it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the return value from currentPoints() function, like this.

**totalPts** = currentPoints(quizPts, labPts, teamPts, homeworkAverage, exam1Pts, exam2Pts);
 currentAverage(totalPts);

Reason is, you declared "totalPts" as local variable in currentPoints().

**"Local variables has function scope only, it is undefined to main function"**.

Do this for all other 
functions(quizAverage,labAverage,teamProject,exam1,exam2, hwAverage,currentAverage)

I hope, this will solve the issue !!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not about functions, it's about variables.

Let's take `quizPts` for instance:

In the main method, you declare this variable, but then you don't do anything with it before sending it to `currentPoints`. Therefore it has an undefined value when you do so (undefined often looks like random in C).

The other variable `quizPts` you use in quizAverage have the same name but is not the same for the compiler.

Try in your main:

`quizPts = quizAverage();`

Answer (score 0):

You asked

> How would I go about fixing this issue?

And the answer is "Use the debugging tool with "watches" window open in your favorite IDE".

It's always very difficult to find an error simply by re-reading the code, but in the debugger you can see all the values of your variables at each moment of time. Specifically, in this example, you would realize that your variables have garbage values from the very beginning (are not initialized), and this value never changes.

Using this approach you could find the reason yourself in time less than necessary to write this SO question. I hope this will help you to save your time in future.

Comment: Wow, did not know that. Thanks for telling me that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you use the variables such as quizPts and labPts without storing any value in them. In your case, you have to store the return value of the function to the corresponding variable before using it. For example, do the same as the following statement:
    quizPts = quizAverage();